# HTML (Bootstrap) cortando conteúdo do XML

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

Então, os dados do estão vindo corretos, porém não estão sendo mostrados. Testei sem o css e funcionou. O problema está nas 3 divs, algúem consegue identificar o porque? (Extremamente URGENTE).

```
    // essas tres divs
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="col-md-7 col-centered">
            <h1 class="h1-large text-center">Mensagens</h1>
            <div id = "b" class="well">


                <?php
                session_start();
                require_once './banco-mensagens.php';
                require_once './conexao.php';
                require_once './banco-chamado.php';

                $cpf = $_SESSION['cpfTecLog'];
                if (isset($_GET['msg'])) {
                    $id = $_GET['msg'];

                    if (isset($_SESSION['cpfCliMsg' . $id])) {
                        $cpfCli = $_SESSION['cpfCliMsg' . $id];
                        $nome = pegarNomeCli($conexao, $cpfCli);
                        echo '<div class="mensagens">'
                        . '<p>Contato: ' . $nome . ' </p>'
                        . '<a href="pag_perfilAbertoCli.php">Visitar perfil</a>';
                        $dom = new DOMDocument("1.0", "ISO-8859-7");
                        $root = lerXML($dom, $conexao, $cpfCli, $cpf, 1);
                        $dom = $_SESSION['dom'];
                        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
                            $mensagem = $_POST['txtMsg'];
                            $msg = addMensagem($dom, $mensagem, $cpf);
                            $root->appendChild($msg);
                            $dom->appendChild($root);
                            # Para salvar o arquivo, descomente a linha
                            $dom->save($_SESSION['nomeXML']);
                            $_POST['txtMsg'] = null;
                            unset($msg);
                            $root = lerXML($dom, $conexao, $cpfCli, $cpf, 1);
                            $dom = $_SESSION['dom'];
                        }
                        // $dom = $_SESSION['dom'];
                        $ver = simplexml_import_dom($dom);

                        foreach ($ver as $xml):

                            if ($xml->cpf_origem == 1234) {
                                echo '<p align="center">' . $xml->mensagem . '</p>';
                            } else if ($xml->cpf_origem == $cpf) {
                                echo '<p align="right">' . $xml->mensagem . '</p>';
                                echo '<p align="right">' . $xml->data_envio . '</p>';
                            } else {
                                echo '<p align="left">' . $xml->mensagem . '</p>';
                                echo '<p align="left">' . $xml->data_envio . '</p>';
                            }
                        endforeach;
                        $_SESSION['cpfCliTec'] = $cpfCli;
                        $_SESSION['abrirPerfilCliente'] = 'comentario';
                        ?>
                    </div>

                    <form method = "POST" action = "pag_comentarios.php?msg=<?php echo $id; ?>">
                        <input class="form-control" type = "text" name="txtMsg">
                        <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg p-large botao" type = "submit" value = "Enviar">
                    </form>
                 // são fechadas aqui
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php
    } else {
        echo '<center>Erro ao abrir comentários!</center>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Consegui encontrar o erro, aparentemente a dentro do if do get não estava achando a class mensagem (sendo que ela está no código.

Comment: No código está `mensagens` e não "mensagem".